# Difference between 11 and 12 catcodes

Tags: macros, package-writing, catcodes

I can only define commands, consisting of catcode-11 symbols or single catcode-12.

*What is the point of this limitation?*

It would be convient for me to define commands, that include following, not used symbols: `!@№:;?*.#-` and, probably a lot of unicode punctuation(I care only about `xelatex`). Of course, I can do it in my own package internals, but if I want to export such unconventional macros, I have to say to user to change catcode. But it seems nobody do such.

I do not see, how it would cause problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Control sequences are of two types:

1. *control symbols*, that is, backslash and *one* non category code 11 character;
2. *control words*, that is, backslash and any sequence of category code 11 characters.

The main problem is in deciding when a control word ends; the rules of TeX tell that a control word ends when the first non category code 11 character is found.

Allowing mixing category code 11 and 12 characters in a control word name would pose problems when parsing the input for transforming it into tokens. You *can* mix them (and also characters with almost any category code) by using

```
\csname <characters>\endcsname
```

but here the termination problem is solved with `\endcsname`.

A philosophical discussion about why Knuth decided in this way might be interesting; but, as things stand, it's simply not possible to do what you want.

You can change the category code of whatever characters you want; but having a standard syntax is surely preferable.

Comment: So, if I make colon part of macroname, it will break code, that relies on fact, that colon ends macroname. Thanks, I see problem.