# clist_if_in:nV fail on a str variable

Tags: expl3, latex3

Is it a bug?

Following code got `BUG STR` and `PASS TL`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { b }
\clist_if_in:nVTF { a, b } \l_tmpa_str
  { \tl_show:n { PASS~STR } }
  { \tl_show:n { BUG~STR } }
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { b }
\clist_if_in:nVTF { a, b } \l_tmpa_tl
  { \tl_show:n { PASS~TL } }
  { \tl_show:n { BUG~TL } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well a string b has catcode 12 and so is different to the letter b with catcode 10.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I forget the catcode. But it is counterintuitive sometimes. (:

Comment: For debugging \tl_analysis_show (or other pretty printer) helps, although... okay I need something to pretty print clist too. // Another case of stored "other" catcode being confusing...

Comment: expl3's `str` is the de-tokenized token list, which is different to the string type in most other programming languages. What you need here is most likely a token list, for example `\l_tmpa_tl`. Also see the beginning paragraphs in `texdoc interafce3`, chap. 16 "The l3str package: Strings".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it useful to think to `str` variables as being a different data type from anything else in TeX, so they can only be compared with each other, but not with other data types unless they are “stringified”.

This is of course not the “truth”. Actually any character token in TeX has a category code assigned at the moment it enters TeX's mouth (in more technical terms, after tokenization). In a `str` variable all character tokens (except space tokens, which retain their category code 10) are assigned category code 12.

The `a` inside the `clist` variable you want to check the presence of, however, under normal conditions, has category code 11.

You might define a (probably slow) routine to check whether the `clist` contains something whose “stringification” is the same as what you want to test.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \l__zhiyuan_clist_str_bool
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \zhiyuan_clist_str_if_in:nn { T, F, TF }
 {
  \bool_set_false:N \l__zhiyuan_clist_str_bool
  \__zhiyuan_clist_str_check:ne { #1 } { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
  \bool_if:NTF \l__zhiyuan_clist_str_bool
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zhiyuan_clist_str_check:nn
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeT { \tl_to_str:n { ##1 } } { #2 }
     {
      \clist_map_break:n { \bool_set_true:N \l__zhiyuan_clist_str_bool }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__zhiyuan_clist_str_check:nn { ne }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \zhiyuan_clist_str_if_in:nn { nV, VV } { T, F, TF }

\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { b }

\zhiyuan_clist_str_if_in:nVTF { a,b } \l_tmpa_str
 { \iow_term:n { YES } }
 { \iow_term:n { NO } }

\zhiyuan_clist_str_if_in:nVTF { a,c } \l_tmpa_str
 { \iow_term:n { YES } }
 { \iow_term:n { NO } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\stop
```

This will print on the console

```
YES
NO
```

Comment: It may be a little faster to only run \tl_to_str once on #2 instead of every iteration.

Comment: @user202729 I was even tempted to remove it, assuming the second argument is a string. Yes, it might be marginally faster. Maybe later I'll modify it.

Comment: Well, it is a solution. But I wonder if there are some user cases that the catcode of item of an `n`-type comma list need to be different with value of a string when used in `\clist_if_in:nV`. Maybe it is more user-friendly and straightforward to write `\clist_if_in:nVTF { abc } \l_tmpa_str`? And for some corner cases, we can provide another version just like `\str_case_e:nn`.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck I'm not aware of such use cases. Do you have any?

Comment: @egreg No. So is it better if we change the internal behavior of `\clist_if_in:nV` when it meets a string variable?

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck I don't think so. String variables have their (quite restricted) usage.